# How to solve InvalidArgumentError for dynamic_partition in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I was trying to use `tf.dynamic_partition()` to replace `tf.gather()` in order to aviod converting sparse representation into dense matrix implicitly.

Here is my code,

```
# edge_source_states = tf.gather(params=node_states_per_layer[-1], indices=edge_sources)
partitions0 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.one_hot(edge_sources, tf.shape(node_states_per_layer[-1])[0], dtype='int32'),
                                                        0)
edge_source_states = tf.dynamic_partition(node_states_per_layer[-1], partitions0, 2)
edge_source_states = edge_source_states[1]
```

The annotation is the orignal use of `tf.gather()`. There was no mistake when using `tf.gather()`, the only problem is that it converts sparse representation into dense matrix and thus consumes a lot of memory.

However, when I use `tf.dynamic_partition()` method instead, I got an error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): partitions[21] = 2 is not in [0, 2)
```

And according to the traceback, this error is caused by the sentence:

```
edge_source_states = tf.dynamic_partition(node_states_per_layer[-1], partitions0, 2)
```

As a novice, I really can't figure it out.

My problems are:

1) I thought my new codes using `tf.dynamic_partition()` is functionally equivalent to the original code using `tf.gather()`. So why there is an error?

2) Is `tf.dynamic_partition()` a solution for avoiding the implicit conversion from sparse to dense as `tf.gather()` does? Are there any other solutions? I really need to control the memory consumption strictly.

Comment: The problem is that your `partition0` tensor has a `2` at some point (and maybe more values over `1`). Which I suppose it means there are repeated values in `edge_sources`. In that case, `tf.dynamic_partition` by itself would not be useful for you, because it assigns each value to a partition, and it cannot "reuse" values. Are there restrictions to the number of times a value may be repeated?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your reasoning about dense and sparse matrices. Both `node_states_per_layer[-1]` and `edge_sources` are regular tensors, and, like you say, both methods should (I think) do the same, when there are no repeated values in `edge_sources`. The second may be faster if you can use it, but if not, I am not sure what it is that gets converted from sparse to dense with `tf.gather`. (I do know that `tf.gather` can be problematically slow, though)

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, I think you are right. The error should be caused by that partition0 has an element larger than 1. In fact, there're always repeated elements in my edge_sources. So it seems like it's infeasible to apply dynamic partition directly. So do you know what else I can do to avoid the conversion and reduce the memory use?